# C# Unit Testing: Mock a Return Type

Tags: c#, methods, mocking, return-type

What is the best way to Mock a return type if we don't care about the actual state of the object.

For example, I am Mocking a method whose return type is: `IEnumerable<Document>`

Now, I can add relevant Nuget package and add necessary namespace so the type Document is defined, however I actually don't need to test anything on the returned object and I feel it's an overkill to include the Nuget and add namespace.

What other alternatives are available instead of including the reference?

Comment: IEnumerable<IDocument> , Document is a concrete type, if you don't care about document abstract it away.

Comment: If you're mocking something with `Document`, it means the code under test is using `Document`, which means you _already_ need the nuget/reference because you're referencing something that depends on it. No?

Comment: @Telastyn Yes, for now I have opted to include it. Was wondering if there was an alternative way.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about the state the method returns in unit test, this is a code-smell. You need to reevaluate the design of this method as it is likely doing too many things at once.

The a method should generally return void if it alters the state of its owning object. This is *not a hard rule*, but if what it is returning is complicated enough to need to be mocked, then I'd guess your method is not one of the exceptions to the rule.

#### Methods should generally either alter state, or return data, but not both. Refactor this method into two separate methods.